# converting TEXT to VARCHAR

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I 've noticed that when converting TEXT to VARCHAR the converted value is silently clipped at 30 characters.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (x TEXT)
-- insert a string that's 50 characters long
INSERT INTO foo(x) VALUES('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR, x)) FROM foo -- retuns 30
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3000), x)) FROM foo -- returns 50
```

My questions are:

1. where is that limit documented / originate from?
2. what's an idiomatic way to make the conversion without having to add an arbitrarily high value? (as in the second `SELECT` statement above)

Answer (score 0):

You can better always specify the varchar-length and the maximum length of a varchar is in Sybase ASE 15.7 and 16.0 16384.

If you try to create a longer varchar, you'll get following error:
Length or precision specification 16385 is not within the range of 1 to 16384.

Tim